# C# generic type : Warning from outer type

Tags: c#, generics, types, generic-type-argument

I have a controller called UserController with generic type T:

```
public class UserController<T> : Controller
{    
}
```

And then, inside this class I have a method called Select() with generic typing:

```
public override T Select<T>(ushort id)
{
    // UserModel is just a Class where I is an integer typed property
    UserModel.I = 2;
    object result = UserModel.I;

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Now in another form class I am accessing this method like this:

```
// This is so far working
UserController<int> us = new UserController<int>(0);
label1.Text = us.Select<string>(0);
```

**Now I am having this warning:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS0693  Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type 
parameter from outer type 'UserController<T>'
```

I am not understanding what it is saying here:

```
Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type 
parameter from outer type 'UserController<T>'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want your *method* to be parameterized with the same type as your class, then you don't include a generic parameter in the method name:

```
public override T Select(ushort id) /* Uses T from class */
```

However, from your other sample it looks like you want to use different types - so use a different name for the parameter:

```
public override TInner Select<TInner>(ushort id)
{
    // UserModel is just a Class where I is an integer typed property
    UserModel.I = 2;
    object result = UserModel.I;

    return (TInner)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(TInner));


    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

(In general, try to pick better names than just `T` or even `TInner` - just as you should pick good names for other parameters, try to convey the *purpose* of the type in the type parameter name)

Comment: Oh Thanks, I did not know that it will conflict with the same names in the same class.

Comment: @RayD'vard - consider that inside the implementation of any of your methods, including `Select`, you may want to refer to the type by which your class is parameterized - e.g. say that it changed what type of `id` parameter is passed - `public override TInner Select<Tinner>(T id) ...` and with your code sample, it's now expecting to be passed an `int`.

Comment: But, If i want to use class type T in the method return type, I am having problem with interface declaration of that method, I am using interface for Select() method. what can i do here?

Comment: @RayD'vard - type parameter names aren't part of the signatures of methods, so I'm not sure on what problem you're encountering. If you're still having issues, try to edit your question and expand it into an MCVE. (Or, if it's radically different now, please complete this question and ask a new one)

Comment: this question is solved, thanks. I will take care of the rest of the part.